# I have no access to getters

Tags: getter, setter

I have created getters in BankAccountServeice class.
Like this:

```
public class BankAccountServeice {
private List<BankAccountServeice> List;


private int accountnumber;
private int pin;
private int balance;

public BankAccountServeice(int accountnumber, int pin, int balance) {

    this.accountnumber = accountnumber;
    this.pin = pin;
    this.balance = balance;

}

public void initalizeBankAccounts() {       
    List = new ArrayList<>();
    List.add(new BankAccountServeice(111, 1234, 15000));
    List.add(new BankAccountServeice(222, 2345, 10000));
    List.add(new BankAccountServeice(333, 3456, 400000));
}

public int getAccountnumber() {
    return accountnumber;
}

public int getPin() {
    return pin;
}

public int getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void setBalance(int balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}
```

When I change class to a different one I can't use my getters.

```
public class CarService {
private List<Car> cars;
private List<Person> persons;
private Car car;
private List<BankAccountServeice> List;


public CarService(Scanner scanner) {
   
    initalizeCars();
    initalizePeople();
    System.out.println(getPin());
    System.out.println(getBalance());
    System.out.println(getAccountnumber());}

}
```

What should I do to have access to these getters? Should I provide path to BankAccountServeice class?

Answer (score 0):

The getters are methods of the BankAccountServeice class (I'm also guessing this should be BankAccountService). So to use them, you first need to create an object of that class.
For example:

```
BankAccountServeice A = new BankAccountServeice(5, 12, 60);
```

You can then call the getters of that object like this:

```
A.getPin();
A.getBalance();
A.getAccountnumber();
```

Comment: You need to indicate what language you're using.  Please edit to add tag(s).